# Yii2 archive installation symbolic link issue

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to install Yii framework via archive file in Windows 7...after downloading the file I tried extracting it into a folder in my C:\wamp\www\bid location, however, I encounter an error saying this:

```
!   C:\wamp\www\bid\yii-basic-app-2.0.2.tgz: Cannot create symbolic link C:\wamp\www\bid\basic\vendor\bin\markdown
    A required privilege is not held by the client.
!   C:\wamp\www\bid\yii-basic-app-2.0.2.tgz: Cannot create symbolic link C:\wamp\www\bid\basic\vendor\bin\yii
    A required privilege is not held by the client.
```

I thought that perhaps Winrar can't extract tgz files so I downloaded 7-zip...Using 7-zip it extracted into a tar file and the tar file was extracted with no errors...For some reason though I do not seem to have the framework folder that seem to be in other people's directory structure...Moreover after trying create my own framework folder and performing this command:

```
yiic webapp C:\wamp\www\bid
```

It states that yiic is not recognized as an internal or external command

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong...I've tried setting this up numerous times and failed

Answer (score 2):

You need to run 7-Zip File Manager in administrator mode.

Right-click the icon of 7-Zip File Manager, and then click "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the command with php since it is actually a external command, i do it like this

`php ./yiic webapp NameOfApp`

This way your terminal understand that yii is a program that runs with php.

Another solution is to add the yii path to your environmental variable, regards

Comment: I tried what you suggested via terminal...typing ./yii webapp C:\wamp\www\bid and ./yiic webapp C:\wamp\www\bid....it said that '.' is not a recognized internal or external command

Comment: you need to call php first, i edited to make it clear, also depending on your specific system it could be php ./yii or php yii, regards

Comment: I got an error stating unknown command "webapp" after performing the php ./yii .. sorry I often have trouble whenever I try to install an application into my computer

Comment: @user3580218 I just edited my answer , this way should work for you